# Apacheds password pattern policy

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I am trying to do user authentication using Apacheds Server. For that I am using Password Policy defined. Most of the authentication requirements are met using these policies, but one thing I am not able to do is password pattern. Is there a way to check if user password meets with particular pattern requirements. Requirements I need are:

- Uppercase character
- Lowercase character
- number
- special character

Comment: I also want to implement alphanumeric password policy, how did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a custom PasswordValidator to achieve this. See DefaultPasswordValidator if you need an implementation sample.

Comment: Where do I put the custom Password Validator? and what would be the Fully qualified class name for it?